# How to split back-end and front-end on same domain?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, routes, react-router

Ive developed my app using React and Nodejs(Express) and Im hosting it on Heroku. Im **hosting it under same domain** for cookies to work properly as Ive had some issues. The problem is that now when I go to [www.mysite.com/login](http://www.mysite.com/login) via link on my site everything works good, but as soon as I refresh page on that URL or type that URL manually I send a GET request to my BE and get 404 (that route doesnt exists).

**How do I prevent such calls?**

Ive handled my routing using **react-router** like this:

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <Router>
        <Sidebar />

        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />

            <Route path="/important" exact strict component={Important} />

            <Route path="/lists" component={ListProtectedRoute} />

            <Route path="/register" exact strict component={Register} />

            <Route path="/login" exact strict component={Login} />

            <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />

            <Route path="/api/*" component={Page404} />

            <Route path="*" component={Page404} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
};
```

The Page404 component basically redirects user to home ("/") page using Route and redirect.

My **Express routes** look like this:

```
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

app.use("/api/todo", todoRoutes);

app.use("/api/lists", listRoutes);

app.post("/api", [check("user_id").exists().notEmpty().isNumeric()], (req, res) => {
    const valErr = validationResult(req);
    if (!valErr.isEmpty()) {
        return res.send(valErr);
    }
    const user_id = req.body.user_id;
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = ?";
    db.query(sql, user_id, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

As you can see I use **/api prefix** for ma BE calls.
Here is a call that I use for registration, userContext.js:

```
const register = () => {
    Axios.post(`${apiUrl}/users/register`, {
        userName: nameReg,
        userPassword: passwordReg,
    }).then((response) => {
        const errors = response.data.errors;
        processErrors(errors);
    });
};
```

The **constant apiUrl** looks like this: **[www.mysite.com/api](http://www.mysite.com/api)**

Here is a link to my site where I host both FE and BE on same domain: [LINK](https://todo-react-node.herokuapp.com/) -> **not working properly**

And here is a link where I host FE and BE separetly on 2 different hostings (Netlify and Heroku): [LINK 2](https://todo-react-node.netlify.app/) -> **this is how I want it to work**

Comment: Hey @MadGrip, were you able to get it working? I went to debug this but it appears your example app is working as expected. When I test it out I see a properly set cookie and the login state is persistent.

Comment: Yes Ive debugged it. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Ive managed to fix it with

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
```